# Laravel 5: Returning Eloquent Model Object as an Ajax Response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to return an Eloquent Model Object as an Ajax Response that i get from search process and i want to pass it to the view.

JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".client_search_option").change(function(){

        var selectedClientTypeVal = "";
        var selectedSmsDecisionVal = "";

        var selectedClientType = $('input[type=radio][name=clientType]:checked');
        var selectedSmsDecision = $('input[type=radio][name=sms_decision]:checked');

        if (selectedClientType.length > 0) {
            selectedClientTypeVal = selectedClientType.val();
        }

        if (selectedSmsDecision.length > 0) {
            selectedSmsDecisionVal = selectedSmsDecision.val();
        }

        //alert(selectedClientTypeVal);
        //alert(selectedSmsDecisionVal);

        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/pages/clientSearchAjax',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, selectedClientTypeVal:selectedClientTypeVal,selectedSmsDecisionVal:selectedSmsDecisionVal},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("An error has occured !");
            }         
        });
    });
});
```

Contoller

```
public function clientSearch(){
    $client_option = Input::get('selectedClientTypeVal');
    $sms_option = Input::get('selectedSmsDecisionVal');

    if($client_option == 'all' && $sms_option == 'all'){
        $ajax_clients = Client::with('clientType')->paginate(5);
    }else{
        $ajax_clients = Client::with('clientType')->where('clienttype_id', $client_option)->where('send_sms', $sms_option)->paginate(5);
    }

    return $ajax_clients->toJson();
}
```

I am sure that `$ajax_client` object is not null, i test it and i am able to get data from database but when i want to pass it to the view(or console) it shows up like `undefined`. How can pass it to the view(or console) and get the values of model's columns. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
return $ajax_clients->toJson();
```

with

```
return $ajax_clients;
```

Laravel automatically converts Eloquent objects to JSON, moreover it will set content type header to **application/json**, which is something you don't do in your code and what might cause the issues you describe.